# Changing color after I save SVG in illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color, layers, cmyk, rgb

I am working with Adobe Illustrator, and my company has given me this mascot file. But the problem is that whenever I am saving this file as an SVG it is changing its original color.

Please see the attached image for your reference.

[image]

> Is it because I am having the color as **CMYK** ?? and after saving it as SVG it is becoming **RGB** ??

Comment: SVG doesn't support CMYK color. If you need it as CMYK, save it as .ai, or .eps, or .pdf

Comment: @Scott is there any way that I can save it as SVG with RGB color ?

Comment: Change the colors to RGB in Illustrator, then export.

Comment: Might be because transparency effects and blending mode is not supported in SVG. source: https://community.adobe.com/t5/illustrator-discussions/colors-get-messed-up-on-export-to-svg/m-p/12230158